# Basic react native question covert Class to Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It might sound silly but I am just learning here
I am trying to convert a component to a function-based component. I did everything right but I am stuck on something very silly

I have this code for Discover

```
export default class Discover extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    items: [],
  };
    cellRefs: {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cellRefs = {};
  }
```

what is the correct way to convert cellRefs to work with the function I have? I tried everything when I do this in my class file it is fine it gives me an object with the things I need.

```
const cell = this.cellRefs[item.key];
```

However,

```
const cell = cellRefs[item.key];
```

is just giving undefined

Full code for the converted component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, Children } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';




const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const cellHeight = height * 0.6;
const cellWidth = width;

const viewabilityConfig = {
itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 80,
};



class Item extends React.PureComponent {
  video: any;
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.video) {
      this.video.unloadAsync();
    }
  }

  async play() {
    const status = await this.video.getStatusAsync();
    if (status.isPlaying) {
      return;
    }
    return this.video.playAsync();
  }

  pause() {
    if (this.video) {
      this.video.pauseAsync();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { id, poster, url } = this.props;
    const uri = url + '?bust=' + id;
    return (
      <View style={styles.cell}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: poster,
            cache: 'force-cache',
          }}
          style={[styles.full, styles.poster]}
        />
        <Video
          ref={ref => {
            this.video = ref;
          }}
          source={{ uri }}
          shouldPlay={false}
          isMuted
          isLooping
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.full}
        />
        <View style={styles.overlay}>
          <Text style={styles.overlayText}>Item no. {id}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.overlayText}>Overlay text here</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}







interface FeedListProps {

}

export const FeedList: React.FC<FeedListProps> = (props) => {
  const initialItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      url: 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/jensun-uploads/shout/IMG_1110.m4v',
      poster:
        'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/jensun-uploads/shout/norwaysailing.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      url:
        'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/jensun-uploads/shout/croatia10s.mp4',
      poster:
        'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/jensun-uploads/shout/croatia10s.jpg',
    },
  ];
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  //this.cellRefs = {};
  //let cellRefs: {};
  //cellRefs= {};
  const cellRefs = React.useRef({})
  const viewConfigRef = React.useRef({ itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 80 })
 

  useEffect(() => {
    loadItems();
    setTimeout(loadItems, 1000);
    setTimeout(loadItems, 1100);
    setTimeout(loadItems, 1200);
    setTimeout(loadItems, 1300);
  }, []);

  const _onViewableItemsChanged = React.useRef((props)=>{
    const changed = props.changed;
    changed.forEach(item => {
      const cell = cellRefs[item.key];
      
      console.log("CALLING IF"+ cell + "        " + item.key)
      if (cell) {
        if (item.isViewable) {
          console.log("PLAY OS CALLED")
          cell.play();
        } else {
          console.log("Pause is played")
          cell.pause();
        }
      }
    });
  });

  function loadItems(){

    const start = items.length;

    const newItems = initialItems.map((item, i) => ({
      ...item,
      id: start + i,
    }));

    const Litems = [...items, ...newItems];

    setItems( Litems );

  };

  function _renderItem({ item }){
    return (
      <Item
        ref={cellRefs[item.id]}
        {...item}
      />
    );
  };



    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={items}
          renderItem={_renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          onViewableItemsChanged={_onViewableItemsChanged.current}
          initialNumToRender={3}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
          windowSize={5}
          getItemLayout={(_data, index) => ({
            length: cellHeight,
            offset: cellHeight * index,
            index,
          })}
          viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          ListFooterComponent={
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={loadItems}>
              <Text style={{ padding: 30 }}>Load more</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  cell: {
    width: cellWidth - 20,
    height: cellHeight - 20,
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    borderRadius: 20,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    margin: 10,
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
    padding: 40,
  },
  full: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
  poster: {
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  overlayText: {
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Could you share some more of the functional component code that is causing the error?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jJMdmtQTMv/

Comment: That is the whole component and https://snack.expo.io/@jenshandersson/optimized-video-flatlist this is the original one

Comment: Is cellRefs accessible in functional component? Did you try debugging the values of `cellRefs` and `item.key`?

Comment: cellRefs is undefined item.key returns an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be enough to use a functional component and use useRef([]) initialized as an array

Working example:
https://snack.expo.io/2_xrzF!LZ

Comment: wow I mean I was so close just my lack of experience I some small mistakes here and there more of syntax. Thank you so much I will spend the rest of the day studying the changes to understand what is going on. I would be glad if you can even explain what you did on the fly :)

Comment: I saw your paste too late, thats why i changed it by my own. From that point of view there was not much wrong with your code. What I changed: Exporting the app as default, assigning the reference in _renderItem {ref => cellRefs[item.id] = ref } and initializing useRef as array React.useRef([])

Comment: i marked the changes in your code with //changed
https://snack.expo.io/SN1F_lQCb

Comment: I used your code on my local machine and it did not work since your answer I spend all the time trying to find out why. Something very strange happened when I "download" you code and run it from expo cli it never works. Online your code and even my old code works just fine. Any tip pleaseee :)?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you could inline your source code into stack overflow, than keeping it in a separate link. However I took a look at the component, and I think the issue is with how you are using props.

On line 91,

```
export const FeedList: React.FC<FeedListProps> = ({}) => {
```

So here, you need to get the props as an argument. Earlier with the class component it was available at `this.props`. However here you need to pass it as below,

```
export const FeedList: React.FC<FeedListProps> = (props) => {
```

Or you may destructure the props as below,

```
export const FeedList: React.FC<FeedListProps> = ({changed}) => {
```

You will also need to modify the interface on line 87 to reflect the type.

Comment: I did update the code still the same issue I am getting undefined. I did lots of debugging here and there the issue is that cellRefs is not referring to the correct place. So when I console cellRefs in the working code "class"  I get that it is an object but for the function code, I get undefined. Another thing is I have zero idea how to set up the interface, I am learning react since like 3 days go so... help :)